# checking a variable against a list of attributes

Tags: list, attributes, prolog, member

How can I change the predicates at the bottom to recursively parse through their lists and compare to X.

```
/*knowledgeBase*/
lives_near_water(raccoon).
lives_near_water(muskrat).
eats_meat(raccoon).
eats_meat(wolverine).
eats_plants(raccoon).
eats_plants(cow).
has_bushy_tail(raccoon).
has_bushy_tail(squirrel).
has_bushy_tail(wolverine).
has_hair(muskrat).
has_hair(squirrel).
has_hair(rat).
has_hair(chipmunk).
has_hair(cow).
has_hair(wolverine).
has_long_incisors(muskrat).
has_long_incisors(rat).
striped(chipmunk).
can_fly(eagle).
has_hooked_beak(eagle).
has_feathers(eagle).
has_feathers(ostrich).
has_feathers(penguin).
can_swim(penguin).
produces_milk(cow).
gnaws_on_wood(squirrel).

/* Rules*/
mammal(X):- has_hair(X), produces_milk(X).
discontiguous has_long_incisors(X):- gnaws_on_wood(X).
discontiguous eats_plants(X):- gnaws_on_wood(X).
rodent(X):- has_long_incisors(X), mammal(X).
herbivore(X):- \+eats_meat(X), eats_plants(X).
carnivore(X):- eats_meat(X), \+eats_plants(X).
omnivore(X):- eats_meat(X), eats_plants(X).
muskrat(X):- rodent(X), lives_near_water(X), \+has_bushy_tail(X).
squirrel(X):- rodent(X), has_bushy_tail(X).
raccoon(X):- omnivore(X), lives_near_water(X), has_bushy_tail(X).
rat(x):- rodent(X), ^(has_bushy_tail(X)), \+striped(X).
chipmunk(X):- rodent(X), striped(X), \+has_bushy_tail(X).
wolverine(X):- mammal(X), carnivore(X), has_bushy_tail(X).
bird(X):- has_feathers(X).
eagle(X):- bird(X), carnivore(X), can_fly(X), has_hooked_beak(X).
ostrich(X):- bird(X), herbivore(X), \+can_fly(X), \+can_swim(X).
penguin(X):- bird(X), carnivore(X), \+can_fly(X), can_swim(X).

/*classify*/
animal_attribute([],X):- X == X.
animal_attribute([T1|Trest],X):- T1(X), animal_attribute(Trest,X).
not_animal_attribute([],X):- X == X.
not_animal_attribute([F1|Frest],X):- \+F1(X), not_animal_attribute(Frest,X).
classify(Ts,Fs,X):- animal_attribute(Ts,X), not_animal_attribute(Fs,X).
```

Classify takes in two lists of attributes Ts and Fs, Ts are attributes that should be true about X and Fs are attributes that can not be true about X.

My idea is to have the two predicates beneath classify recursively check each member of Ts/Fs against X, I am also trying this recursively because I do not know how many members their will be and I am not allowed to change the format of classify's variables.

This is homework so I am not asking for you to make the changes, but the proper format for making this recursive.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: made classify section recursive but I am still getting a syntax error: operator expected
after both of the recursive functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question while waiting for a response, if anyone runs into a similar problem though here is the solution that fixed my problem.

```
animal_attribute([],X):- X == X.
animal_attribute([T1|Trest],X):- call(T1,X), animal_attribute(Trest,X).
not_animal_attribute([],X):- X == X.
not_animal_attribute([F1|Frest],X):- \+call(F1,X), not_animal_attribute(Frest,X).
classify(Ts,Fs,X):- animal_attribute(Ts,X), not_animal_attribute(Fs,X).
```

you need to use a call operator to force prolog to treat the first variable as a predicate.
the format for call is this:
call(predicate, var1,...,varN).
Hope this helps!

Comment: You should not post code to solve your homework because this may lead people having the same homework to believe your answer is ok, and worse than that to cheat. Your solution may give the right results but its code is poor: besides the problem in the previous comment, do you not notice that there is some duplication in your two predicates? Have you compared them? Can you use only one of them? If you manage to simplify your code just do not post it.